# ENYOJS : Passing headers in an ajax call

Tags: ajax, enyo

How do I pass headers in an enyo.ajax call ?

```
enyo.kind({
name: "enyo.sample.AjaxSample",
kind: "FittableRows",
classes: "enyo-fit ajax-sample",
components: [
    {kind: "FittableColumns", classes:"onyx-toolbar-inline", components: [
        {content: "YQL: "},
        {kind: "onyx.Input", name:"query", fit:true, value:'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where text="san francisco, ca")'},
        {kind: "onyx.Button", content:"Fetch", ontap:"fetch"}
    ]},
    {kind: "FittableColumns", classes:"onyx-toolbar-inline", components: [
        {content: "URL: "},
        {kind: "onyx.Input", name:"baseUrl", fit:true, value:'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json'}
    ]},
    {kind: "onyx.TextArea", fit:true, classes:"ajax-sample-source"},
    {name: "basicPopup", kind: "onyx.Popup", centered: true, floating: true, classes:"onyx-sample-popup", style: "padding: 10px;", content: "Popup..."}
],
fetch: function() {
    var ajax = new enyo.Ajax({
        url: this.$.baseUrl.getValue(),
                headers: [{
                      "user-username" : "testuser",
                      "user-pwd" : "tester"
                }]

    });
    // send parameters the remote service using the 'go()' method
    ajax.go({
        q: this.$.query.getValue()
    });
    // attach responders to the transaction object
    ajax.response(this, "processResponse");
    // handle error
    ajax.error(this, "processError");
},
processResponse: function(inSender, inResponse) {
    // do something with it
    this.$.textArea.setValue(JSON.stringify(inResponse, null, 2));
},
processError: function(inSender, inResponse) {
    var errorLog = "Error" + ": " + inResponse + "! " + (JSON.parse(inSender.xhrResponse.body)).error.description;
    this.$.textArea.setValue(JSON.stringify(inSender.xhrResponse, null, 2));
    this.$.basicPopup.setContent(errorLog);
    this.$.basicPopup.show();
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close here.  What you want to do is the following:

```
var ajax = new enyo.Ajax({
    url: this.$.baseUrl.getValue(),
    headers: {
         "user-username" : "testuser",
         "user-pwd" : "tester"
    }
});
```

`headers` is an object, not an array.